# Error installing generator hyperledger composer on MAC OS

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install the Hyperledger Composer development environment on my Mac. But when I try to install CLI tools with the command:

npm install -g composer-cli

the following error message shows up. I have tried to rollback the node version to 6/7 without success.

npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support

```
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.


> pkcs11js@1.0.12 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/pkcs11js
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/Users/jloo/anaconda/bin/python" is v3.5.1, which is not supported by gyp.

gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.

gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failPythonVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:492:19)

gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:474:14)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:264:7)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:363:11)

gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:558:12)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0

gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/pkcs11js

gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.1

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2

gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1`enter code here`

npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.12 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above
```

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pasting an error log is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use **nvm** and install Node version 8 - Stable. And try running by using that node version.

Answer (score 0):

Node 9 isn't supported, python 3 won't work with npm and node-gyp. It needs to be python 2.
Please see
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/stable/installing/installing-prereqs#macos
to help you get the appropriate pre-reqs

Answer (score 0):

For me it works if I uninstall everything and install *NodeJs* version 8 as in:

```
# node -v
v8.17.0
# npm -v
6.13.4
```

then after that install with (after apt getting *node-gyp*) `--unsafe-perm` like:

`npm install -g --loglevel error --unsafe-perm composer-cli`

hope that helps...